# Soft bricked​ Sony Xperia M

Tags: boot-loop

I was trying to unlock the boot loader of my Sony Xperia M.
May be I undertook a wrong step and bricked my phone.
It doesn't have recovery mode.
How can I solve the issue
Please help

Comment: You'll need to flash it

Comment: Could you please explain in detail

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to flash the phone to solve the brick. This works on locked and unlocked bootloader.

- Download the firmware (search on Google)
- Download and Install the flash tool. The default directory of installation of flash tool will be **C:\Flashtool**
- Open the drivers (C:\Flashtool\Drivers) directory and install the Flash mode and Fast boot drivers.
- Now Open Flash Tool. Click on the “Black Lightning icon” at the top left corner.
- Then choose flashmode from given two options.
- Now browse to  where you saved the firmware previously download.
- See the right hand side of window under the “Wipe” tag,.  If you don’t want to delete all user  data and don’t want a factory reset then you should uncheck them.
- Click on “Flash” button.
- After clicking on “Flash” Button in above step, now FlashTool will prepare file. When prompted the notification of connecting your phone, connect it in flashmode: Press Volume down button and then insert usb in phone.
- Wait untill the process finishes. Et voilà, your phone should boot normally.

Comment: Will this work for custom ROMs

Comment: If in ftf file format it should.

Comment: You're welcome. Just follow the steps. And let us know if it works.